# How to print a full pyramid pattern?

Tags: android, eclipse

My expected output

[image]

I tried the following code, but it prints only one *. I am confused where the code has went wrong.
                int rows = 6, k = 0;

```
            for(int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0) {
                for(int space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space) {
                    t2.setText("  ");
                }

                while(k != 2 * i - 1) {
                    t2.setText("* ");
                    ++k;

                }
                t2.setText();

            }
```

Comment: Please be more specific, do you want to print pyramid with asterisks?

Comment: What does your code actually print? What debugging have you done?

Comment: to add text to current in textView you need to use t2.setText(t2.getText() + text); In your code t2.getText(); do nothing.

Comment: What do you think `setText` does? It will overwrite anything already existing. You need to build a string, then set the string.

Comment: do i need to set three strings for three setText statements?

Answer (score 1):

This will work like a charm...

```
int y = 5,x = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < x-i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < i+1; k++)
    {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }


    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer. However, it prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 stars. Expected answer is 1, 3, 5, 7, 9. I'm sure he can adapt it though.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   char s;
   int l;
   System.out.println("Enter the Letter : ");
   s = sc.next().charAt(0);
   l = Character.getNumericValue(s)-9;
   for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) 
   {
        for (int j = 0; j < (l - i); j++) 
            System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
            System.out.printf("%c%s",(char)j+65,"");
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) 
            System.out.printf("%c%s",(char)j+64,"");    
        System.out.println();             
   }
```

```

Comment: i am trying it in eclipse android so system.out.println statements do not work

Comment: use Log.d('HereGoesSomeKeyThatYouCanEasilySearch','AndHereOutputLikeInSYSO');

Answer (score 1):

The OP could call this:

```
String s = createCharPyramid(5, "*");
t2.setText(s);
```

and define this method:

```
private String createCharPyramid(int numberOfRows, String mySymbol){
    String s = "";
    String sep = System.lineSeparator();
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < (numberOfRows - i); j++){
            s = s + " ";
        }
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            s = s + mySymbol;
        }
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
            s = s + mySymbol;
        }
        s = s + sep;
    }

    return s;
}
```

**This answer is based on MrRobot's answer. His answer is a pure java solution and would correctly show a pyramid in the console. So, if you like this answer give him a +1.**